# How do I do an interaction frame transformation in classical Hamiltonian mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames, hamiltonian-formalism

I am fairly proficient in quantum mechanics but am mostly self taught in classical mechanics (out of Goldstein, Borben and Stehle, and Wikipedia).  My question relates to a classical analogue of the *interaction picture* technique from time-dependent perturbation theory in quantum mechanics.  I have studied in detail [classical contact transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Generating_function_approach) and generating functions, but so far have failed to find a general prescription for removing an unwanted term from a Hamiltonian by a frame transformation.

### tl;dr

Consider a Hamiltonian with two components
\begin{equation}
H = H_0 + \epsilon H_1
\end{equation}
where $\epsilon$ is a small multiplicative constant; We consider $\epsilon H_1$ to be a perturbing Hamiltonian. The object is to devise a canonical transformation $(q, p) \rightarrow (Q, P)$ such that

\begin{eqnarray*}
\dot{Q} &=& \frac{\partial}{\partial P} K \\
\dot{P} &=& - \frac{\partial}{\partial Q} K
\end{eqnarray*}
and with $K$ directly proportional to $\epsilon$.  If we let $G$ represent the generating function of the canonical transformation, I would think that since
\begin{eqnarray}
K = H+\frac{\partial }{\partial t}G
\end{eqnarray}
then we would want $\partial G/ \partial t = - H_0$.  Is such a transformation always possible? How do I find the generating function for this transformation?

### Quantum case

I want to remind everyone there is a well-known and general prescription for doing this in quantum mechanics.  In the transformed frame, the new Hamiltonian is
\begin{equation}
K = U_0^\dagger (H - H_0)U_0 = \epsilon U^\dagger_0 H_1 U_0
\end{equation}
where the propagator $U_0$ satisfies the Schrodinger equation $i \hbar \dot{U}_0 = H_0 U_0$.  It's trivial to calculate the transformed operators for any observable.  For example, the transformed phase space coordinate operators are $Q = U_0^\dagger q U_0$ and $P = U_0^\dagger p U_0$.  Since the [Ehrenfest theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem) is a real thing, I would expect the equations of motion for the quantum operators to agree with the classical variables produced by the canonical transformation technique.

Answer (score 1):

Canonical perturbation theory uses action-angle coordinates to describe an integrable Hamiltonian $H_0(J)$ (where $J$ is the action). A perturbation term can then be added such that the total Hamiltonian is non-integrable
$$
H = H_0 +\epsilon H_1
$$
We then have Hamilton's equations
$$
\dot J = -\epsilon \nabla _Q H_1 ,\qquad \dot Q = \nabla _JH_0 + \epsilon\nabla_JH_1
$$
Generating functions can then be used, expanded to desired order and then a Hamilton-Jacobi equation can be written. The Hamiltonian can be truncated and the fundamental equation of Poincaré can be written.